# MySQL PHP Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Is it possible to create pagination without getting all elements of table? 
But with pages in GET like /1 /666…

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you implement pagination in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267892/how-do-you-implement-pagination-in-php)

Comment: It's all great, but total number of records is required.

Comment: it's all great. So just read the amount off your Database: `SELECT count(*) from table`

Comment: i can`t, it`s too slow now, searching optimization ways http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749831/mysql-records-count-with-condition

Answer (score 2):

It usually involves issuing two queries: one to get your "slice" of the result set, and one to get the total number of records. From there, you can work out how many pages you have and build pagination accordingly.

A simply example:

```
<?php
$where = ""; // your WHERE clause would go in here
$batch = 10; // how many results to show at any one time
$page  = (intval($_GET['page']) > 0) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
$start = $page-1/$batch;
$pages = ceil($total/$batch);

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM tbl $where";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$total = $row['total'];

// start pagination
$paging = '<p class="paging">Pages:';
for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
    if ($i==$page) {
        $paging.= sprintf(' <span class="current">%d</a>', $i);
    } else {
        $paging.= sprintf(' <a href="?page=%1$d">%1$d</a>', $i);
    }
}
$paging.= sprintf' (%d total; showing %d to %d)', $total, $start+1, min($total, $start+$batch));
```

And then to see your pagination links:

```
...
// loop over result set here

// render pagination links
echo $paging;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just FYI: it's not necessary to do two queries, you could use the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS select option: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using mySQL's `LIMIT` clause. Most pagination tutorials make good examples of how to use it.

See these questions for further links and information:

- [How do you implement pagination in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267892/how-do-you-implement-pagination-in-php)
- [Searching for advanced php/mysql pagination script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280230/searching-for-advanced-php-mysql-pagination-script)
- [more results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+pagination)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT` to paginate over your result set.

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = 1 LIMIT 5, 10
```

where LIMIT 5 means 5 comments and 10 is the offset. You can also use the longer syntax:

```
... LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10
```